# how can i assign array positions to strings which have been splited by the strtock_r in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char pch[]="encrypt galvin;double royal;";
    char *str=pch;
    char *ptr;
    //pch = strtok (dir,";");

    while ((ptr =strtok_r(str,";",&str))){
        printf("%s\n",ptr);

        char *token=ptr;
        char *en;
        char cwd[524];
        while((en =strtok_r(token," ",&token))){
            //  char *gal = strtok(NULL," ");
            strcpy(cwd,token);

            if (strcmp(token,"double")==0) {
                strcat(cwd,cwd);
                printf("Double %s Done.\n", cwd);
            }
            //printf("%s\n,gal");
        }
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Above is my code. but i tried running it for several times it's not doing what i want. I'm asking for your help.

I want to make that code where by if  an array `pch` has got several commands it splits them into into single commands e.g.

```
encrypt galvin
double galvin
```

After doing that it splits those commands into substrings e.g.

```
encrypt galvin
```

further split into `encrypt` followed by 
`galvin`  and similarly to the other task.

Then after that the `if` startment must compare if the string in the split substrings is `encrypt`. if it confirms then it would pick the second string from the split string (`encrypt galvin`) that is `galvin` then it wrks on it. For example above in my code I only used a double command so when it goes to a string `double galvin` it picks it, also splits it and picks the word `double` and compares it. Then if it's the one then it goes further to pick the word `galvin` and it doubles it thus returning `galvingalvin`  as the output. so am kindly requesting for your support

Comment: I know your English is not good, but you really need to learn how to type and how to split up your text to make it easier to understand, that's the same in any language.

Comment: Ohk sir. I will try improving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line produces undefined behavior:

```
strcat(cwd, cwd);
```

because the source and destination are not allowed to overlap. You can make a copy of `cwd` so you can concatenate it.

```
char cwd2[524];
strcpy(cwd2, cwd);
strcat(cwd, cwd2);
```

You're not using `strtok_r()` correctly. The first call to `strtok_r()` in a loop passes a pointer to the string being parsed as the first argument, and a pointer to some *other* pointer as the third argument. When you repeat these calls in the loop, the first argument should be `NULL` -- that tells `strtok_r()` that you want to continue parsing the same string.

And the pointer to the token is the value returned from the function, not the third argument.

After you find the word `double`, you need to read the *next* token to get the word that should be doubled. Your code is doubling the current word, which is just `double`.

Here's the corrected code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char pch[]="encrypt galvin;double royal;";
    char *cmd;
    char *ptr;
    //pch = strtok (dir,";");

    for (cmd = strtok_r(pch,";",&ptr); cmd; cmd = strtok_r(NULL, ";", &ptr)) {
        printf("%s\n",cmd);

        char *word;
        char *ptr2;
        char cwd[524];
        for (word = strtok_r(cmd, " ", &ptr2); word; word = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptr2)) {
            if (strcmp(word,"double")==0) {
                char *word2 = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &ptr2);
                strcpy(cwd, word2);
                strcat(cwd, word2);
                printf("Double %s Done.\n", cwd);
            }
        }
    }
    return  0;
}
```

Comment: If i make  a copy of cwd to  concatenate the substring,The code returns only the first two split tasks in the 1st  while lop ie   encrypt galvin. And double galvin on a new line. Instead of giving me an output as  galvingalvin .

Comment: Your basic logic seems wrong. When you see the command `double`, you have to wait until you read the *next* token before doubling it.

Comment: So how can i go about it so that i get  clear results for example...if i had written many double commands and i wanted it to return all does commands when executed .

Comment: I've completely rewritten the answer

Comment: Thank u Mr.Barmar.